# Graphql is showing error while running with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have newly installed graphql through nodejs, while setting up the built schema i got the following error
**TypeError: builtScheme is not a function**.
the code is given below

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const graphqlHttp = require('express-graphql');
const { builtScheme } = require('graphql');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api',graphqlHttp({
    schema: builtScheme(`
    type RootQuery {
        events:[String!]!

    }
    type RootMutation{
        createEvent(name:String):String


    }
    scheme{
        query: RootQuery
        mutation: Rootmutation
    }
    `),
    rootvalue:{
        events:()=>{
            return ["Romatic comedy","missing u","dont u dare"]
        },
        createEvent:(args)=>{
            const eventname =args.name;
            return  eventname
        }

    },
    graphiql:true

}))

app.listen(3000,(err,result)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('node is unable to start');
    }
    else{
        console.log('node is running at 3000');
    }
});
```

if anybody know the solution,please revert back to me?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your looking for [buildSchema](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#buildschema), However you are `const { builtScheme } = require('graphql');`.

Try: 
`const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');`

Comment: Thank you...sorry it was my mistake